# How to pan only with left mouse button in flutter interactive viewer?

Tags: flutter, interactive, viewer, pan, zoom-sdk

I have an interactive viewer which encapsulates an image. I want the user to only be able to pan with left mouse button and open a menu on right click. Currently the menu opens with right click and image also get panned with right click. Is there a way to stop panning with right click in interactive viewer?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: _controller,
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(10000),
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        minScale: 0.0001,
        maxScale: 10,
        constrained: true,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage(widget.imagePat),
                filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,
                isAntiAlias: true,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.11, 0.09),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(24, 0, 0, 0)),
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make a copy of the InteractiveViewer script to your library.
- Find GestureDetector, and change 'onScale' event to 'onPan'.
- Then make a few adjustments to those functions.

(smooth animation won't work after that)
Also, it probably won't work on mobile.